# Trying to show custom product field on stock.inventory.line view

Tags: odoo-15

I'm trying to show custom product field on stock.inventory.line but keep getting error "Field stock.inventory.line.outdated cannot find dependency 'stock_move_ids' on model 'product.template'."

This is in my module manifest file under dependencies:

```
'depends': ['base', 'product', 'stock', 'sale', 'account', 'stock_account']
```

This is inside python file:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class StockInventoryLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.inventory.line'

product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product')
instrument_field = fields.Many2one(related='product_id.instrument', string='Instrument')
```

This is in my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_stock_inventory_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.inventory.line.tree</field>
            <field name="model">stock.inventory.line</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_stock_inventory_line_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="instrument_field"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I get that probably the error is with the model stock.inventory.line but I don't know what to use here.

Comment: Here is screenshot where the field should be displayed

https://ibb.co/nBThBft

Comment: You've tagged "odoo-15", The model ```stock.inventory.line``` not exists any more in Odoo 15. it's replaced with ```stock.quant``` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model `stock.inventory.line` doesn't exists any more in Odoo 15. it's replaced with `stock.quant` model.

If you are using Odoo 14 or previous versions, the `product_id` field in `stock.inventory.line` defined as `Many2one` from `product.product` and you redefined it to link it with `product.template`.

The `product.product` inheriting all fields from `product.template` so you can get `instrument_field` directly from product.product

Another thing, `stock_move_ids` defined in `product.product` and because of your overriding, Odoo couldn't find it in `product.template`

Please remove the `product_id` from your code as below.

```
from odoo import models, fields

class StockInventoryLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.inventory.line'

    instrument_field = fields.Many2one(related='product_id.instrument', 
    string='Instrument')
```